# What basis token is generated in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I could create token by REST api and netsuite UI too. I faced below error after creating token more times.

```
This user has exceeded the number of active access tokens this role.
```

I thought tokens are created based on these three combinations
[image: Access token generation]

1. Application (Consumer key, Consumer secret)
2. User (Employee)
3. Role

Even though I change app name and role name for the user, I am getting the same error.

I searched in documentation, I could not find anything regarding that.

On what basis , Netsuite tokens are generated?

How to generate more tokens without revoking existing tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered with [Suite Answer 83936](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83936/) :

> There can only be a maximum of 25 access tokens a user can have in an account. If a user tries to create another access token even if he already has 25 access tokens then he will receive the error stated above.